# jeasyui combogrid onLoadSuccess to trigger click / select if return 1 record

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

In jEasyUi combogrid, is it possible to trigger select or click if the AJAX return only single record? so that the user won't have to click on the single record to close the box.

```
<th data-options="field:'itemCode',width:130, 
    editor: {
      type:'combogrid', options:{
        panelWidth:450,
        delay : 400,
        mode : 'remote',
        idField:'ITEM_CODE',
        textField:'ITEM_CODE',
        method:'post',
        url:'server_setup.php',
        required:true,
        loadMsg: 'Searching...',
        onLoadSuccess: function(obj) { 
          if (obj.total == 1) {
            //click on the single record
            $('#datagrid-row-r3-2-0').trigger('click'); <---- this one work
          }
        },
        columns:[[
            {field:'ITEM_CODE',title:'Item Code',width:130},
            {field:'ITEM_NAME',title:'Item Name',width:250},
            {field:'QOH',title:'QOH',width:100}
        ]],
        onBeforeLoad: function(param) {
          if (!param.q || param.q.length<3) return false;
        }
    }   
}">Item Code</th>
```

How can i get the #datagrid-row-r3-2-0?

Comment: use `.trigger('click')` jQuery function.

Comment: Nope, no error return, and this is my code. $(this).trigger('click');

Comment: But you have not specify in your post, that - on which element you want to fire a `click` event? please elaborate more to get correct answer ..

Comment: Sorry, this is my findings.
$('#datagrid-row-r3-2-0').trigger('click');
this one work, but how can i know the auto generated ID?

Comment: It is depend on what data you get in your `AJAX Response obj data`. And on the basis of return data you can Find your `datagrid row`.

Comment: can you post What data you get in your `onLoadSuccess: function(obj)` in obj.

Comment: well, this is the data. [{"ITEM_CODE":"RT95002","ITEM_NAME":"XYZ","QOH":"599.00"}]. But i've tested the $('#datagrid-row-r3-2-0').trigger('click'); is working, just need to find out how to get the ID.

Comment: Well it's very difficult but if you can post your HTML Data (after DOM rendered) then we can find the particular ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64615/discussion-between-prog-and-fire).

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the DOM, I'm able to trace the id by the following code.

```
if (obj.total == 1) {
  $('.panel, .combo-p' ).each(function() {
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
        selectedId = $(this).find('.datagrid-btable').children().children().attr('id');
        if (selectedId != undefined) {
          $('#'+selectedId).trigger('click');
            return;
        }
      }
  });
}
```

I think jEasyUi should have a better way than this workaround, it is quite dangerous of returning wrong Id. Anyone can assist?